# Is it better to hard code everything or use the ui?

Tags: 7

Is it better to hard code everything or to use the ui?  For example, is it better to field and entity with the UI or to add fields/instances programmatically?  Does it really matter?  What is the 'best practice'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use code you can:

- Version control the field settings.
- Lock the field, so it can't be deleted or altered in the UI.

It's always a good idea to keep as much as possible in code, for when you need to roll out changes etc. This is why i prefer the above method, even though it is more time consuming during development. Depending on your use case, you may save a lot of time doing this however.

Comment: do you mean using modules like views which allow exports by 'above method'?

Comment: @user1750 No I was talking about creating fields programmatically

Answer (score 1):

The two don't have to be pulling in different directions imho. It's possible (where the modules support it) to use the UI to make the changes, and export to code. For me this is the ideal to aim for. [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) is a great step in that direction, but not the only example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andy, using the UI for creating your content types and fields and then exporting that in code with the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module is the way to go. Features has its own quirks you need to get used to, but IMO it beats the headaches of having to write and maintain your code for doing what you can do with a few clicks in the UI.